# Find pairs in set of files

Tags: python, file, dictionary

From set of data files how to find if the same pair is available in other files.

Eg: I have 5 files with pair of nodes in `col[0] col[1]` they both are pairs definitely.

I have to check which all pairs repeat in all the 5 files.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Input: Just a part `col[0]` and `col[1]` are the columns to be concentrated from all the 5 files.

```
00022d7317d7 00022d9064bc 1073260810 1073276155 819251 440006 819251 440006
00022d9064bc 0030650497a0 1073260810 1073272525 819251 440006 819251 440006
00022d9064bc 00904b8150f1 1073260810 1073260999 819251 440006 819251 440006
00022d9064bc 00904ba69d11 1073260810 1073260857 819251 440006 819251 440006
0030650c9eda 0030658a61de 1073260811 1073260813 820356 439224 820356 439224
0030650c9eda 00904b16c23a 1073260811 1073260813 820356 439224 820356 439224
0030650c9eda 00904bacceaf 1073260811 1073260813 820356 439224 820356 439224
0030650c9eda 00904bf058d0 1073260811 1073260813 820356 439224 820356 439224
00022d0e0cec 0030650c9eda 1073260813 1073262843 820187 439271 820187 439271
00022d176cf3 00904ba8b682 1073260813 1073260962 817721 439564 817721 439564
```

Expected output

Suppose if we consider the first row `col[0]` and `col[1]`

```
00022d7317d7 00022d9064bc
```

I have to compare this pair in all the 5 files and find which file and how many times does this pair appear. The same way i need to compare all the pairs in all 5 files.

Note: I know this is not a code providing service. So I would appreciate directing me to some near by sample or any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Please show the code you have so far, and explain what specific problem you are having difficulty with.

Comment: Is each one of those lines a separate file? Or is this just a single file, and you have a bunch of similar files?

Comment: More generally, give us a complete (but minimal) set of input and desired outputs, instead of a vague description of the problem you're trying to solve, along with the code you have and which part you're stuck on. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details.

Comment: @ekhumoro I very well know that this is not a code providing service.. I could not actually make any start towards this type. I have also tried searching for any near about sample but i do not find any .. So i do not have any code to show.

Comment: @abarnert This is a part of one file. I have bunch of files with similar data.

Comment: @SitzBlogz: You can't make _any_ start? You don't know how to loop over filenames, open files, read lines, parse them into columns, etc.? In that case, you _do_ need a core-writing service. If that's not the case, then again, go read the help, and come back and write us some code showing exactly where you're stuck, with complete (but, again, minimal) inputs and outputs. Until you do that, there's no way to answer this that's appropriate to SO.

Comment: @abarnert. Exactly. I can never understand why anybody claims they don't know how to do something if they haven't even bothered to try.

Comment: @abarnert I can do all these "loop over filenames, open files, read lines, parse them into columns, etc" But I am stuck how to compare the the pair in all the file. I am not getting the logic about that.

Comment: @gboffi Thanks !! I got some idea now.. I am sure i can get some logic from the sample.

Comment: @SitzBlogz: Then _do_ it. Show us the data structures you're building out of your input, and then a comment saying `# I don't know what to do here`, then the code using the result, and then explain what the inputs are, what the desired outputs are, and what the "I don't know what to do here" should be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting my answer to another recent post:

Assuming a folder structure like `/path/data1.txt` `/path/data2.txt` ... `/path/dataN.txt` `/path/script.py` and no other files in there.

1. Initialise two dictionaries that will keep track of things over all the files. One will store counts "*pair* seen *N* times" the other will store filenames "*pair* seen in files *[data1, data3]*"
2. Get all the `.txt` files in an outer loop. For each file:

   1. Read through all the lines in an inner loop. For each line:

      1. Split out the first two columns, using space as a separator, call that a pair
      2. Increase the count of how many times it has been seen overall, in one dictionary
      3. Add the current filename to the list of filenames for this pair, in the other dictionary

Then every pair where the location list is 5 long, has been seen in all the files. Print those pairs.
Then dump the count dictionary to see how many times each pair appears.

(Untested):

```
from glob import glob
import os

masterCount = {}
masterLocations = {}

for datafile in glob('*.txt'):
    filename = os.path.split(datafile)[1]

    for line in open(datafile):
        columns = line.split(' ')
        pair = columns[0] + ' ' columns[1]

        masterCount[pair] = masterCount.get(pair, 0) + 1
        masterLocations[pair] = masterLocations.get(pair, []) + [filename]

for pair, filenames in masterLocations.iteritems():
    if len(filenames) == 5:
        print pair, "found in all 5 files"

for pair, count in masterCount.iteritems():
    print: pair, "found", count, "times in total"
```